# Creating default object from empty value, using codeigniter db class

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using a CI stack and making a simple database query and getting an error on this line:

```
$row->available_seats = $source_event_details->available_seats - $tot_rsvp_sub;
```

Here is the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Creating default object from empty value
```

I have tried to do the following, but its not working and doesn't make sense to me beacuse I've never had this error before.

```
if(!isset($row))
    $row = new StdClass();
```

When I do a print_r on both of those arrays they are both showing as populated arrays of stdClass object.

Comment: can you add more code where you are getting error?

Comment: did you do print_r($row);?

Comment: Yeah, neither of the arrays are empty, they are both showing integers for that value